# Angular CLI 1.7.2 + Webpack 4.1.0 not building with --prod

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular5, webpack-4

So I recently ran an `ng update` on my angular5 project and updated the angular cli to version 1.7.2 and webpack to 4.1.0. I can build fine with no errors using `ng build` but when I run `ng build --prod` I get the following errors:

```
78% advanced chunk optimizationD:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:465
                throw new Error("Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.addGroup instead");
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.addGroup instead
    at Chunk.set (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:465:9)
    at D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:206:13)
    at Compilation.seal (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:602:8)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:504:17)
    at D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:289:11
    at _addModuleChain (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:505:11)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (D:\WORKSPACE\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:475:14)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Not sure what to do from here, any help? I can post my `webpack.config.js` and `packages.json` if it would help.

Comment: Maybe try reporting it as an issue on the Angular repository? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/new

Answer (score 2):

I bootstrapped an fresh project with Angular CLI 1.7.2 into a GitHub repo and updated it step-by-step in each commit to make it build with Webpack 4.0.1.

https://github.com/fernandoespinosa/angular-cli-webpack4-sample/

To address your current issues you will have to update a few packages:

```
npm i -D --save --force html-webpack-plugin@latest
npm i -D --save --force extract-text-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.0
```

Remember that `CommonsChunkPlugin` has been deprecated so you will have to remove it from *webpack.config.js*. You will have to `ng eject` this file and play around with it a little bit.

```
ng eject --aot=true --target=production --build-optimizer=true
```